# One git command to create new local branch, push to origin, track origin

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-checkout

A common part of my workflow is:

```
git checkout -b new_branch origin/master
git push origin new_branch
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/new_branch
```

Is there a way this could be boiled down to one command?  I'd like to be able to set up an alias so that this can be done with something quick to type such as:

```
gitnew new_branch parent_branch
```

A bash solution is acceptable, but would be neat if it were pure git.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way this could be boiled down to one command?

Yep, add `&&` between each command

```
git checkout -b new_branch origin/master &&
git push origin new_branch &&
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/new_branch
```

On single line

---

***`git alias`***

You can use git alias to define those set of command as well.

```
git config --global alias.newb "!f(){ git checkout -b $1 origin/$2 && git push origin &1 && git branch --set-upstream-to origin/$1 };f"
```

$1 = name of new branch
   $2 = name of parent branch

**How to use:**

```
git newb new_branch_name master
```

Comment: Would you mind replacing the other instances of new_branch with $1?  Also, are the quotes you have around the first $1 necessary?

Comment: Its just a sample to show you how to do it.  You actually don't need the quotes.  They are there in case you will have spaces

Comment: getting the error:  Expansion of alias 'newb' failed; 'find' is not a git command